error trying to connect: unexpected EOF
cxp@R9000P:~/solana_learn/hackathon/orbit_len$ anchor deploy
Deploying cluster: https://indulgent-restless-snowflake.solana-devnet.quiknode.pro/68a14a3306ba9773105b138c7981ec4350f288fa
Upgrade authority: /home/cxp/.config/solana/id.json
Deploying program "orbit_len"...
Program path: /home/cxp/solana_learn/hackathon/orbit_len/target/deploy/orbit_len.so...
Error: RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending request for url (https://indulgent-restless-snowflake.solana-devnet.quiknode.pro/68a14a3306ba9773105b138c7981ec4350f288fa): error trying to connect: unexpected EOF
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.

